# How to give keycodes from a properties file in javafx

Tags: javafx, keyevent, properties-file

Currently i have configured JavaFX keyEvents for key board controllers for each task. What i want is to configure there keys from a properties file rather than hard coding in the code.

The implementation :

```
 final KeyCombination keyCombinationShiftC = new KeyCodeCombination(
            KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);

    javafx.event.EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent> handler = event -> {
        if (keyCombinationShiftC.match(event)) {
            try {
                if (finalSubTotalPrice > 0) {
                    paymentAction();
                } else {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                    alert.setTitle(app.values.getProperty("WARNING_TITLE"));
                    alert.setHeaderText(app.values.getProperty("INVALID_NO_OF_ITEMS"));
                    alert.setContentText(app.values.getProperty("INVALID_NO_OF_ITEMS_DIALOG"));
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case F10:
                try {
                    removeAction();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case F1:
                try {
                    searchField.requestFocus();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case F5:
                try {
                    customVatDiscountCalculation();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
             }
```

The ENTER+CNTRL_DOWN, F5, F10, F1 keys need to be assign for other keys without changing the code using a properties file.

If i try to get the Strings from the properties file, i fail to do that. as below. It says a constant expression is required for the case.

```
    public static final KeyCode REMOVE_KEY = KeyCode.getKeyCode(app.values.getProperty("REMOVE_KEY"));


    switch (event.getCode()) {
            case REMOVE_KEY:
                try {
                    removeAction();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

  }
```

Comment: so what's the problem - just do it :) Hint: have a look at the api doc of Key/Code/Combination

Comment: please check for the issue.question is updated

Comment: ah I see - you need to read a tutorial on basic java ;) And the error tells you exactly what's the problem .. hint: you can lookup the keys before entering the switch

Comment: I did. still giving the same issue

Comment: you did read up on switch statement in a basic tutorial didn't you ;)

Comment: yes i did. can you point out what is wrong with it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html - if that doesn't help you I cant, sry ;)

Comment: ok. so do i need to create Enum for each key?

Comment: No, you need to check the key combinations one by one. If you're sure some of the combinations only contain a single key you could also use a `Map` to replace the switch: `Map<KeyCode, Callable> codeMap = new EnumMap(KeyCode.class); codeMap.put(KeyCode.valueOf(app.values.getProperty("REMOVE_KEY")), this::removeAction); ... Callable c = codeMap.get(event.getCode()); if (c != null) {try { c.call(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} event.consume();}`

Comment: @fabian could you put it as an answer please?